# Python treeview update tag

Tags: python-3.x, treeview

I have inserted items into a Python `treeview` with tag option.

```
tree.insert("", 'end', 'item1', text='item1', tags=('new',))
```

Is it possible to change the tag `"new"` to something else later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify any of the options of an item. So if you want to change `'item1'` tags to for example `'old'`:

```
tree.item('item1', tags=('old'))
```

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview) about `ttk.Treeview`:

> item(item, option=None, **kw) Query or modify the options for the
>   specified item.
>
> If no options are given, a dict with options/values for the item is
>   returned. If option is specified then the value for that option is
>   returned. Otherwise, sets the options to the corresponding values as
>   given by kw.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Great, please select the answer as accepted. Thanks.